# Creating game, currently using SQL Server to store data, looking for better alternatives

Tags: c#, sql-server, vb.net

I have been using SQL Server 2014 to store a DB for the game to use with multiple tables...it's a football game so there are quite a few tables...players, coaches, owners, GMs, scouts, teams, etc...

The question I have is will end users need to have SQL server installed to utilize the DBs in the game? If so, I need to switch to a different option and am wondering what the best option would be for storing large amounts of data which will not require end users to have something special installed to utilize them?

CSV seems the obvious easy answer but I think that would be too much data for a CSV file to handle well.

Comment: some sort of embedded DB like SQLite or SQL Server Compact?

Comment: can always store it in xml files, or create your data file format to suit your needs

Comment: "game to use with multiple tables...it's a football game so there are quite a few tables"...You probably are going to need something a little more elegant than csv files. I would go with the free express version of sql server or start from scratch with another small embedded rdms.

Comment: Would end users need a version of that installed to use a free SQL version? I'm specifically looking for something that doesn't require them to have anything special to use the files...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [SQLite](https://www.sqlite.org/).  It's a lightweight high-performance database with modern features like indexes, transactions, and so on.  There are ADO.NET components for it also.  It works great, it's open-source, and it's free.  The only downside to SQLite is that it doesn't come with a tool to view and manipulate a database, but you can download [a separate tool](http://sqlitebrowser.org/) for that.

You could also use Microsoft Access.  You would need to have a copy of Access installed to create a new database, but the OLE DB components needed to modify or access the database are part of Windows.  Microsoft Access's database engine isn't as fast or as reliable as SQLite, but if you have Access installed then you have nice tools to view the database, create new tables, and so on.

Answer (score 1):

The data you are storing, what is your requirement for it?

1. Should this data be exactly the same for all users, and not to be edited?
   Then you should store the data on a remote location, to prevent tampering, and any changes made to the data will affect everyone.
2. Should the data just "follow" the game, and tampering is not a problem? 
   Store it as a file alongside the game, the format of the file is up to you, whatever format you choose, parsing will require some time.

If you choose 1, then choosing the right database depends on the structure of the data and how you would use it. I think that's an entirely different discussion, and for hobby-projects it's not important. Choose what you know the best.

If you choose 2, splitting the data into multiple files would greatly increase performance if you don't need to load all data at the same time. Find out what you need when (IE: If you just need all player info, load the player file; If data is required in another fashion, for example you load by a team-basis, including team info, players, matches, etc; Then store your data with all team info in one file.)

The format of the data is relatively unimportant depending on what you need it for. Should it be open for editing, a human-readable format like XML or JSON would be preferred. If space is a requirement, go for CSV. My main tips here would be to go for a well-known format, and not create your own. Not only will you find existing parsers to well known formats, your options later will be more flexible.

Comment: No, the data is going to be unique for each person because of the generation code that randomly generates attributes, name, stats,etc...

Comment: If the data is unique to each user, I would suggest storing it in files along with the game.

Is this game played as a standalone game on a users computer, or is it network-based; If the latter, is there a game server of any sort?

If it is standalone, storing it in files would be the easiest to achieve I guess, like you would save a game-state. For your own convenience you could parse the data and put it into more suitable data structures in the memory once they are loaded, this way you can use the efficiently after the loading. This is basically what a database would have done for you.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server Compact (aka SQL Server CE) is an embedded database.  It does not require the end user to have anything installed.  Be sure to use version 4 though (https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=17876).  3.5 had some pretty serious limitations.  CE has some differences (like column defaults being part of the column definition, not a table-level constraint), but for the most part you won't run into anything too surprising.  There are official implementations of LINQ and EF for SQL Server CE as well.

Answer (score 0):

I believe all answers so far really add to the discussion. I would like to throw LocadDB (SQL Server) there as another option for you.

And as a side note, depending on the amount of information you need to store on files, you might want to go with some DBMS, either local or remote. Working with too many files or files with too much data can get really cumbersome and/or lower your game's performance.